# Centering a custom navigation bar item using layout anchors

Tags: ios, autolayout, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, layout-anchor

I have created a custom navigation item (with both title and a `UISearchBar`) to replace the standard navigation title on iOS and I am trying to center it in a UINavigationBar using layout anchors.

However, the layout constraint `[self.navigationItem.titleView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.centerXAnchor].active = YES;` does not work and the `UIView` containing the search bar shows up on the left side of the `UINavigationBar`.

Other constraints:

- The width should be 1/3 of the screen width
- I want to avoid setting width as a constant to make the view responsive in response to orientation and other layout changes

How to center the navigation bar item?

`ScreenViewController.m`:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create the search bar
    self.searchBar = [SearchBar new];

    // Create a new UIView as titleView (otherwise I'm receiving an error)   
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [UIView new];

    // Add into view hierarchy and turn off auto constraints
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.navigationItem.titleView];
    [self.navigationItem.titleView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:self.searchBar.view];            
    [self.searchBar.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    // Set anchors for the wrapping view
    [self.navigationItem.titleView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.widthAnchor multiplier:1.0/3.0].active = YES;
    //[self.navigationItem.titleView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:50.0].active = YES;
    [self.navigationItem.titleView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.navigationItem.titleView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.navigationItem.titleView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

    // Set anchors for the search bar
    [self.searchBar.view.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationItem.titleView.widthAnchor multiplier:1.0].active = YES;
    //[self.navigationItem.titleView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:50.0].active = YES;
    [self.searchBar.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationItem.titleView.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.searchBar.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationItem.titleView.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    //[self.searchBar.view.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationItem.titleView.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    //[self.searchBar.view.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationItem.titleView.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.searchBar.view.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationItem.titleView.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

Expected result:
[image: Centering search bar]

What I get (the title view is not centered):
[image: Centering search bar problem]

View hierarchy:

[image: View hierarchy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, changing only the title view, setting its width anchor to a fraction of the navigation bar's to make it responsive:

```
// Create search bar and set it as title view
self.searchBar = [SearchBar new];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar.view;

// Turn auto constraints off
[self.searchBar.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

// Set the layout anchors
[self.navigationItem.titleView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:250.0].active = YES; // Had to set the width to a constant
// Was still causing problems
//[self.navigationItem.titleView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.widthAnchor multiplier:1.0/3.0].active = YES;// Still need to access the navigation bar's anchor
[self.navigationItem.titleView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:50.0].active = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is both impossible and illegal. You are not making a "custom navigation bar item" at all (as claimed in your title). You are attempting to add a subview directly to a navigation bar. You can't do that. The way to put something into a navigation bar is to assign it into a view controller's `navigationItem`, either as a bar button item or as the navigation item's real `titleView`. (You call your *variable* `titleView`, but you are not in fact making it the navigation item's `titleView`.)

Comment: I started calling directly the `self.navigationController.navigationBar` because I thought I needed access to its `widthAnchor`, `topAnchor`, `bottomAnchor`, `centerXAnchor`. How can I otherwise make sure the new `navigationItem` occupies 1/3 of the screen width?

Comment: You are not in charge of the placement of things within the navigation bar. So don't try to be in charge. You can have a view in a view as the real `titleView` and dictate their sizes using _internal_ constraints, but you cannot dictate the placement of the `titleView` _itself_ (it will be centered but that's not up to you). Or you can put a custom view in a left bar button item and dictate its size with _internal_ constraints. But its exact placement is not up to you.